# How can I set the cookie by using requests in python?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

HELLO I'm now trying to get information from the website that needs log in.

But I already get 200 response in the reqeustURL where I should POST some ID, passwords and requests.

headers dict have requests_headers that can be seen in the chrome developer network tap. form data dict have the ID and passwords.

```
login_site = requests.post(requestUrl, headers=headers, data=form_data)
status_code = login_site.status_code print(status_code)
```

I got 200

The code below is the way I've tried.

***1. Session.***

when I tried to set cookies with session, I failed. I've heard that session could set the cookies when I scrape other pages that need log-in.

> ```
> session = requests.Session()
> session.post(requestUrl, headers=headers, data=form_data)
> test = session.get('~~') #the website that I want to scrape
> print(test.status_code)
> ```

I got 403

***2. Manually set cookie***

I manually made the cookie dict that I can get

> ```
> cookies = {'wcs_bt':'...','_production_session_id':'...'}
> r = requests.post('http://engoo.co.kr/dashboard', cookies = cookies)
> print(r.status_code)
> ```

I also got 403

Actually, I don't know what should I write in the cookies dict. when I get,*'wcs_bt=AAA; _production_session_id=BBB; _ga=CCC;'*,should I change it to dict {'wcs_bt':'AAA'.. }?
When I get cookies

```
login_site = requests.post(requestUrl, headers=headers, data=form_data)
print(login_site.cookies)
```

in this code, I only can get
**RequestsCookieJar[Cookie _production_session_id=BBB]**

Somehow, I failed it also.

How can I scrape it with the cookie?

Comment: It's possible that, after login, the website redirects you to another page which is actually responsible for setting the cookies, and your script is never hitting that page.  It's also possible that they're blocking you because your user agent is set to Python/Requests.  Without any further information about which site you're trying to scrape, it's impossible to give you any more information, but for the record you should definitely be using requests.Session if you want to persist cookies automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How can I know actual page that is responsible for setting the cookies?The website that I wanted to scrape was the 'https://engoo.co.kr/'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scraping a modern (circa 2017 or later) Web site that requires a login can be very tricky, because it's likely that some important portion of the login process is implemented in Javascript.

Unless you execute that Javascript exactly as a browser would, you won't be able to complete the login.  Unfortunately, the basic Python libraries won't help.

Consider [Selenium with Python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), which is used for testing Web sites but can be used to automate any interaction with a Web site.